# How to deal with matches pairwise in regex?

Tags: regex, markdown, pairwise

I have a basic understanding of regex (I think) - but lookahead and all that just escapes me :(
So I have a sense that this should be doable with rx, but I have no idea how to do it.

I want to copy Markdown from [Notion](https://notion.so) into [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/). Both support MD - but different flavours. So I thought I could do some search & replace in a text editor to deal with the differences.

But: strikeout text is "`~~text~~`" in Notion and "`<s>text</s>`" in MediaWiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting how one can think overly complex. It suddenly hit me that I don't have to worry about counting or doing advanced stuff looking at individual occurences of `~~`, but that I could look at the paired case using a search string "`~~(.*?)~~`" and a replacement "`<s>$1</s>`".

Nice & easy

Comment: Thanks for your attention - but the forward slash is correct: I want the HTML s-tag.

Comment: `~~(.*)~~` will not work. Some say you need `~~(.*?)~~`

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1 - temporary blindness, I guess ;)

Comment: @sln: it did work, but you're right: lazy expansion IS better. Thanks!